# Не создаются таблицы в базе данных MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, orm

Сообшение об ошибке:

```
at factorymanagment.Starter.main(Starter.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]

2018-07-22 13:22:58.187  WARN 29312 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2018-07-22 13:22:58.191  WARN 29312 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
2018-07-22 13:22:58.198  INFO 29312 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-07-22 13:22:58.297  INFO 29312 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-07-22 13:22:58.303 ERROR 29312 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
```

Answer (score 0):

В сообщении об ошибке всё написано:

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Это означает: при запросе на соединение не указан пароль пользователя (root) или указан неверно.

P.S. Неправильно, когда программа работает с базой с правами root